# Turn off superscript in todo package

Tags: superscripts, todonotes

Todo package by default can display todo notes either as a superscript or as a marginpar (the package has appropriate options). Is there a way to display todo notes as normal text (without patching the package itself)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the following in your preamble after loading the package.

```
\makeatletter
\let\@tododisplay\space
\makeatother
```

This will put a space between the To Do text and what it is next to.

Comment: This didn't work in lyx 1.6.5. Started giving errors instead.

Comment: @apoorv The solution still works in regular latex. If you make a minimal document in Lyx and test it, and you still get errors, you should make a new question (referencing this one) and explain what the error is.